# How to externalize application properties outside mule 4

Tags: mule, mulesoft

I'm currently looking for a solution to externalizing the application properties for the different environments in Mule 4. The idea is to make it flexible but also to make access per role available. I have seen several solution like Custom Configuration Properties Provider. I'm looking for a solution that might be easy to implement.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

thanks in advance

Comment: This is in the documentation. What is the actual issue? Saying easy to implement is too ambiguous and doesn't meet Stackoverflow guidelines.

Comment: We are looking for a solution that we can maintain outside the mule application and it can be used by al the api's that we build. Does that answer the question?

Comment: Asking for recommendations of products, libraries, etc is off topic for Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. If instead you are instead asking for recommendations of a design the question seems not specific enough and lacking focus. Both are valid cause for a question to be closed by the community. For example an specific question could be: I am implementing properties server MagicProperties 1.2.3 and I am having error XXX implementing the PropertiesConfig interfase, this is the code, errors, etc.

Comment: @aled Thanks for your response. I will close it